# How can I add specific lengths of silence between tracks with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to combine several audio files with a background image to create a video. I know I can add audio files with a map as

```
-i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2
```

but how can I add specific lengths of silence between the tracks of audio while having a single image as the background?

Comment: I adjusted the title to better match the question, thanks for undeleting it. I'm sure others will find this helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I undestood your question correctly, you can supply multiple inputs and concatenate them:

```
ffmpeg \
  -loop 1 -i image.jpg
  -i audio1.wav \
  -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc \
  -i audio2.wav \
  -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a][3:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" \
  -map 0:v -c:v copy \
  -map "[outa]" -c:a aac -b:a 192k \
  -shortest \
  out.mkv
```

What this does:

- This uses a single image as input #0 (but you can exchange `-f lavfi -i testsrc` with your actual video file). Inputs #1 and #3 are the two audio files you want to use.
- Input #2 is a filter that generates five seconds of silence.
- You then concatenate all audio streams with the `concat` filter.
- To add third audio file, for example, you'd specify two additional audio inputs (silence and your actual track), add the input label for the `concat` filter (i.e., `[4:a][5:a]`), and increase `n=3` to `n=5`.
- The output file uses the input video as-is (`-c:v copy`), and the audio is re-encoded with AAC at 192 kbit/s. It is required to re-encode the audio stream since you are applying a filter.
- The `-shortest` option ensures that encoding ends when the shortest (either video or audio) stream ends.